# Spring creating dashboard using web sockets for live updates

Tags: spring, sockets, spring-boot

The front page of my web app is a dashboard, where I pull out information such as:
Latest entered clients, 5 top male clients, and female and also some calculated statistics.
The approach I went with first, was creating endpoints in my controller that would calculate such things and return a JSON file with the results, and then make an Ajax call and put the data in the html file. But I was told the best way to do this, would be to use Web Sockets, considering that when another users puts a client in, simultaniously he needs to show up on the dashboard.

Following a tutorial what I have so far is this :

```
public class MyMessageHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

@Override
public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
    // The WebSocket has been closed
}

@Override
public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
    // The WebSocket has been opened
    // I might save this session object so that I can send messages to it outside of this method

    // Let's send the first message
    session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("You are now connected to the server. This is the first message."));
}

@Override
protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage textMessage) throws Exception {
    // A message has been received
    System.out.println("Message received: " + textMessage.getPayload());
}
}
```

And the websocket endpoint :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
 public class WebsocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

@Bean
public WebSocketHandler myMessageHandler() {
    return new MyMessageHandler();
}

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(myMessageHandler(), "/my-websocket-endpoint");
}

}
```

But this tutorial shows how a message will be sent-received real time.

My controller has and endpoint like this:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="getDashboard/{gender}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody List<Client> getTopClients(@PathVariable("gender") 
 char gender) {
    return clientService.findTop5ByGenderOrderByResult_DataResults_ScoreDesc(gender);

}
```

What I'm trying to understand is, where do this service so that it is called as long as the connection is open, so if there's any update, it updates the dashboard real time.

I guess what I'm trying to understand is the skeleton, of what this would look like using web sockets.
Just an overview of its logic/example.
Any help is appreciated and I apologize as I'm a beginner, I dont fully understand how to switch from what I had done before, and I'm trying to learn best practices.

Comment: I thought it's usually the other way around: connected client checks once in a while if there are any updates, and server sends updates if there were. Usually servers will not maintain connections to clients to push updates continuously, as this puts a hard cap on number of clients that can be connected at once (some servers might be more potent than others, but the cap's always there). So in the end, you should use whatever's on the side of a client to tug on server once in a while. For example, every 10 seconds sounds fine.

Comment: Thank you so much ! That makes sense, but what I don't understand is what changes  does the client check on ?
Example, I have a service that returns 5 people with highest score. And that service changes when new people are added on the database. Because it should get recalculated.
I just don't understand where to put such services so that the dashboard always has the latest 5 people with highest score or the latest 5 entered people. I've seen examples like the ones I've shared and [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/), but those examples transmit messages.

Comment: It really depends on how you implement the whole thing. One way is to just make a query and upon receiving response simply to clear UI and redraw it completely. That usually is the simplest approach.